# Ruby: What Does STDIN.gets mean?

Tags: ruby, io

Recently, i was reading legacy ruby script and hopefully to convert some of them to python.

I understand the concept of 'STDIN' and done some google search. However, there is no documentation about this stand alone statement: 'STDIN.gets.' What's the return value? Does it secretly get all the input and store it in some default places, or it is simply a piece of unfinished meaningless legacy code i should delete?

Comment: Could it be that it was to interface with some other script/program that expects to send a value to your script, but that your script has since been updated to no longer need it, but still accepts it for legacy purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `p STDIN.method(:gets)` you get `#<Method: IO#gets>`.  This means that the `gets` method if defined in the IO module.  Knowing that, you can then read the official documentation of `gets` here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-gets

The `gets` method does not store its data in some default place, it returns it as the return value of the method.  If that return value is being ignored, then the data is lost, but it could still be useful to call `STDIN.gets` for its side effects: `gets` will pause the execution of your thread and wait for input from the standard input.  This would give the user a chance to review what the Ruby script has already done and terminate it early if the user wants to.

Comment: Thank you! Now i get what the original author means: just hold and wait:)

Comment: Sorry i am new to Ruby. In the future, i should also search the parent module for function definition:) As i want to learn ruby inside-out and really understand the structure of language, do you think "Pragmatic Programmers' Guide" it's a good place to start? (i have previous experience in OOP and algorithms in C++)

Answer (score 1):

When working with Ruby, `irb` is your friend. irb is the interactive Ruby shell, or REPL.  You can try your statement in irb:

```
2.3.0 :001 > STDIN.gets
hello
 => "hello\n"
```

After typing `STDIN.gets`, the system waited for input.  I typed `hello` and then pressed the Enter key.  irb indicated that the return value of the expression was `"hello\n"`.

This shows that:

1) `gets` returns when, and only when, the user presses Enter or equivalent.

2) `gets` returns the string that was typed, pasted, etc., including the terminating Enter key.

You'll probably see a lot of calls to `chomp` on strings returned by gets.  This is because the trailing "\n" is rarely wanted. `chomp` returns a string with the "\n" removed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation Keith! yeah i does see a lots of "chomp". I am just wondering that in the future,if the ruby's documentation does not answer my doubt, what are some other resources u may recommend?

Comment: You're welcome.  I like the "pickaxe book" (https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0).  Also, Stack Overflow, of course.  Other than that I just google and experiment in irb.